# How to detect central key of the Nokia S40 device using Java ME?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, nokia, nokia-s40

I am fresher in j2me. I like to implement an application that should detect central key of the S40 device.I use this code

```
if(keyCode==-5&&c==2) { 
c=1;
repaint(); 
} else {
c=2; 
repaint(); 
}
```

it work only on simulator and but not work in S40 device.Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

Comment: What is central key? Are you asking about fire key?

Comment: C is just a variable and the button use for setting the values of c

Comment: This kind of questions is very usefull in the game application development.

Answer (score 0):

This is the key code for nokia s40 mobiles,

```
-1 = UP     -2 = DOWN    -3 = LEFT   -4 = RIGHT     -5 = CK
```

For more info look at this article, [Canvas KeyCodes.](http://j2me.wikia.com/wiki/Canvas_KeyCodes)